# Reading equations: Upside down A

Tags: notation

what does this equation mean? I´m really bad in reading those, so if somebody explained it, I would really appreciate.

> $f_i(x,y)\ge 0\quad\forall i\{0,1,2\}$

Comment: Personal pet peeve: It is not an equation. An equation is a statement that two things are equal (has an equals sign). Your question involves the statement that $f_i(x,y)\geq0$ if $i$ is 0,1, 2.

Comment: totally agree, my bad.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The symbol "$\forall$" means "for all" or "for every".

"$\forall i \in \lbrace 0,1,2 \rbrace$" means
"for all $i$ in the set $\lbrace 0,1,2 \rbrace$".

Comment: thank you. It means i can only be 0,1,2 am I right, and nothing more basically?

Comment: @dan: It means that the statement is true for *each* of these three values of $i$: $f_0(x,y)\ge 0$, $f_1(x,y)\ge 0$, and $f_2(x,y)\ge 0$. It says nothing about $f_i(x,y)$ if $i$ is not $0,1$, or $2$.

Comment: Why can't I get "\{" and "\}" to render (I've used them before here)? "\lbrace" and "\rbrace" work fine...

Comment: ok I get it now, thanks to all of you guys!

Comment: And is there a prounounciation for it or if I see ∀α.r should I read that as "for all alpha dot r"?